# Why does the function call take place after the increment of variable x in this JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence

Why is the function call not executed first? According to JavaScript operator precedence function call is having precedence 19 but as you see in the below code the function call is executed after the increment of the variable x. That means the function call outputs the incremented value of the variable x which is 1.

```
 var x; // variable x;
 x = 0; // assigned the value 0 to variable x;
 ++ x + alert(x); // function call outputs the value 1;
```

As you saw in the above code the function call did not get executed first.  If the function call is executed first then it must show an alert box with the number 0 but the alert box showed the number 1 on it. This means that after the increment of variable x only the function call is executed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: function does not have a higher precedence. Going to go 1) ++x, 2) addition, 3) execute alert 4) add x to alert

Comment: i read this but this didnt answer my question pls help me

Comment: Please, oh please, use punctuation characters in your questions in the future. Those walls of text were really hard to decipher (also, if everything is emphasized then nothing is).

Comment: Your code is the same as `(++x) + alert(x)`. `++x` evaluates to 0 and the return of `alert()` is undefined (I think, but it does not matter). It is as if you wrote `++x; alert();`

Comment: @epascarello i didnt get what you are trying to tell me can you make it clear for me

Comment: the function gets executed when it is reached. It does not have higher precedence.

Comment: but how @LuketheGeek because function call is having higher precedence

Comment: Yes but the `+` operator adds `(++x) + (alert(x))`. Try `var foo = ++x + alert(x)`.

Comment: @epascarello function call is having a precedence of 19 if you check the MDN documentation you can clearly see but i gotta know why function call is not executed before the increment of variable x

Comment: Function call has higher precedence over addition

Comment: I see no `new` in your code.

Comment: @LuketheGeek :- so what you are trying to tell is that though the postfix increment and function call is there the function call is not going to affect the increment of variable x. function call and increment operator only affects the addition operator not each other but in here it tries to affect each other : ++ alert('function call is executed first');

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding precedence. The higher precedence of the function call parentheses means that it will behave as

```
++ x + (alert(x))
```

Instead of

```
(++ x + alert)(x)
```

Comment: so what you are trying to tell is that though the postfix increment and function call is there the function call is not going to affect the increment of variable x. function call and increment operator  only affects the addition operator not each other but in here it tries to affect each other :      ++ alert('function call is executed first');

Comment: Not sure since your comment is hard to follow, but it means that `++alert()` will try to run `alert()` instead of `(++alert)()`. Please start sentences with a capital letter and add `backtick around code`. Please don't type at SO like you would in a text message.

Answer (score 2):

Precedence determines how an expression is *parsed*, not necessarily how the order it is *evaluated*. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence):

> Operators with higher precedence become the operands of operators with lower precedence.

This means, when parsing the expression, you can think of it more like the *lowest* precedence operators are "considered" first - and then each operand of that lowest precedence operator is evaluated. You may also consider it like, the lowest precedence operators "separate" the expression before the higher precedence operators. They define a point at which one piece's results do not affect another piece's.

So when parsing your expression, you first consider the *lowest* precedence operator, and separate the expression into two implicit expressions:

```
(++ x) + (alert(x));
```

Operands are evaluated left to right always, so since the operators of the two sides don't actually interact (in a way that can be parsed), these pieces are evaluated in this order:

```
++x //x = 1
alert(x) //alert(1)
1 + undefined // results of the above two, added together
```

Function calls having a higher precedence doesn't mean they get absolutely executed first, it just means that they serve as a singular "unit" that won't get separated by most other operators.

Comment: so what you are trying to tell is that though the postfix increment and function call is there the function call is not going to affect the increment of variable x. function call and increment operator only affects the addition operator not each other but in here it tries to affect each other : ++ alert('function call is executed first');

Comment: @Kevin All I'm saying is that operator precedence determines the *grouping*, and then each group is evaluated left to right. In your example there, `++` has a lower precedence so its operands are grouped implicitly: `++(alert('function call is executed first'))`

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say "operands are evaluated left to right" rather than "code is executed left to right", since the whole point here is that code is _not_ executed in a strict left-to-right order.

Answer (score 1):

Code is interpreted from left to right and **then** according to precedence.

```
 >++       (Precedence 19)
 >x        (symbol)
 >+        (Precedence 14)
 >alert(x) (Precedence 20)
```

Now going from up to down (same as left to right) we notice that ++ has a higher precedence than + so we execute ++ first. Following downwards, + is slower than the function call, so we execute the function call first.

Look at this other example

```
++get_a_number()
```

Here the function call has higher precedence than the increment, so it will be evaluated before.

Comment: so what you are trying to tell is that though the postfix increment and function call is there the function call is not going to affect the increment of variable x. function call and increment operator only affects the addition operator not each other but in here it tries to affect each other : ++ alert('function call is executed first');

Comment: That is correct. You read the code from left to right and execute it, if it has higher precedence than the next operator, or wait with execution, if the next part has higher precedence.

Comment: You don't go through the entire line and pick the one with highest precedence first.

Answer (score 1):

When you break it down, at the root of your expression, you have a `+` operator. The way `+` works is that first its LHS is evaluated to a value, then its RHS is evaluated to a value, and then they are added together.

The LHS is:

```
++ x
```

So that will be evaluated first.

Then the RHS is evaluated:

```
alert(x)
```

And then they are added together.

You can think of operator precedence as a tiebreaker between two operators fighting over *the same operand*.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence):

> Operator precedence determines how operators are parsed concerning each other. Operators with higher precedence become the operands of operators with lower precedence.

So if you had this expression:

```
++f(2)
```

The question is, do we interpret this as:

```
(++f)(2)
```

Or as:

```
++(f(2))
```

Since function call has higher precedence than `++`, the answer is the second one.